# After updating Angular we get a "process is not defined"

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

We have updated our Angular 7 app to Angular 12 by using the migration steps from the angular website. The Angular CLI on npm start gives us only a warning

```
'node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version. To opt-out of the deprecated behaviour and start using 'sass' uninstall 'node-sass'.
```

But if we start our app we get the following error:

```
util.js:109 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at Object.71732 (util.js:109)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Module.77741 (documents.component.ts:19)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Module.86100 (list.component.ts:9)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Module.15204 (sysbiz.service.ts:10)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Module.65790 (not-found.component.ts:10)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

Have haven't found anything how can I solve this issue and I get a blank page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add following to your `polyfill.ts` file:

```
(window as any).process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```

Comment: Thank you. But do we know if there is a bug somewhere in the build process? I am facing the same issue and it goes on to check node_debug in process.env in the util.js.