# How to solve error 'process is not defined' in Angular 17

Tags: angular

After adding implementation for canActivate in angular routing, the following errors started:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined**

[image: process is not defined error]

For that I found two "solutions":

1 Add this code as script to index.html file:

```
<script>window.process = { env: { NODE_ENV: 'production' } };</script>
```

*That I don't really like*

2 Add a polyfill.ts file:

```
import * as process from 'process';
window['process'] = process;
```

Both solutions gives me the error:

**Uncaught TypeError: util.inherits is not a function**

[image]

That I wasn't able to solve.

I have no ideia what is happening and I could not find any solution in the internet.
I tested the CanActivateFn and is working fine, but the non authenticated page gives me the errors described.

For context, this is my app.routes.ts:

```
import { authGuard } from '@core';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent, LoginComponent, MainComponent, MainHomeComponent, NotFoundComponent } from '@pages';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    title: 'ReservationApp',
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: MainHomeComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', title: 'Log in', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

When going to root page being not authenticated the described errors occur.
Any ideas on how to solve it?

Edit 1:

This is my guard:

```
export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  try {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('tk');

    if (!token) return false;

    const expiry = (JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))).exp;
    return expiry * 1000 < Date.now();
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Edit 2:
After opening a [issue](https://github.com/pillarjs/send/issues/225) in send repository, the reason why the error happened is:

> Your issue is due to send being a package which is meant to stream files from the filesystem of a server to a client.

I understood, but don't know how to solve it! I'm not using any of the packages that are giving me errors.

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646434/after-updating-angular-we-get-a-process-is-not-defined) help?

Comment: can you share your guard ?

Comment: Apparently you are using the package `send` uses a quite old version of `mime`. It uses the `process.env` feature of NodeJS, which causes the issues you are describing when running in the browser. I would suggest to use a different package if possible, or ask the author of the package to update the dependencies.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, guard code added! I'm using this catch due to a exception 'localStorage is not defined'.

Comment: @JSONDerulo, that was my understanding too! But didn't really knew this was an bug!

Comment: @DavidR, as described in the question, this solutioned the process error and gives me a new one

Comment: Following @JSONDerulo orientation, I opened a [issue](https://github.com/pillarjs/send/issues/225) in send repository.